# Matlab - Defining a math function

Tags: matlab

What is the difference in defining a function with syms or @ (x)?

For example:

```
syms f(t)
f(t) = 0.5*cos(280*pi * t) + 0.5 * sin(260*pi * t) + 0.5 * cos(300*pi * t);
```

and

```
f = @ (t) 0.5*cos(280*pi * t) + 0.5 * sin(260*pi * t) + 0.5 * cos(300*pi * t);
```

Thanks

Comment: The one is a symbolic expression and the other is not. The symbolic expression can be manipulated symbolically. If you don’t need symbolic manipulation, don’t use symbolic expressions, they are expensive to evaluate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Symbolic function

```
syms f(t)
f(t) = 0.5*cos(280*pi * t) + 0.5 * sin(260*pi * t) + 0.5 * cos(300*pi * t);
```

defines a [**symbolic** function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/create-symbolic-functions.html). This means that there is *no loss of precision* when using the function. The results are always *exact*:

```
>> f(1)
ans =
1
```

Also, you can apply *symbolic operations* to the function. For example, you can compute its derivative function, among [other operations](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/performing-symbolic-computations.html):

```
>> g = diff(f)
g(t) =
130*pi*cos(260*pi*t) - 140*pi*sin(280*pi*t) - 150*pi*sin(300*pi*t)
```

This is a new symbolic function, which can be used normally:

```
>> g(1/260)
ans =
140*pi*sin(pi/13) - 130*pi + 150*pi*sin((2*pi)/13)
```

Note how, again, the result is exact. If you want to obtain its *numerical* value (which will necessarily be an *approximation*) you can convert to [`double`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/double.html) floating-point representation:

```
>> double(g(1/260))
ans =
 -84.154882885760415
```

or, if you need more decimals, you can use [`vpa`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/vpa.html):

```
>> vpa(g(1/260), 50)
ans =
-84.154882885760413712114778738680201384788201830179
```

Using symbolic functions incurs a cost in efficiency: the code will generally be *slower* than with standard functions. Besides, they are limited to *mathematical* operations, whereas standard functions can do many other things, such as dealing with text or files.

### Standard, numerical function

```
f = @ (t) 0.5*cos(280*pi * t) + 0.5 * sin(260*pi * t) + 0.5 * cos(300*pi * t);
```

defines a [standard, **numerical** function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/function-basics.html). More specifically, it defines an [anonymous](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html) function, and then defines `f` as a [handle](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/creating-a-function-handle.html) to that function, with the result that `f` can be used as the function name.

You can "only" use this function to pass inputs and get outputs as result. Besides, with the default floating-point `double` data type you may encounter some [numerical inaccuracies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/686439/why-is-24-0000-not-equal-to-24-0000-in-matlab). For example, `f(1)` gives

```
>> f(1)
ans =
   0.999999999999963
```

instead of the exact result `1`.

In contrast with the symbolic case, Matlab doesn't know how to compute its derivative, so in this case you would have to do it *numerically* (using finite differences), which is an *approximation* (both because of using finite differences and because of working with floating-point values):

```
>> t0 = 1/260;
>> h = 1e-9;
>> (f(t0+h)-f(t0))/h
ans =
 -84.154498258826038
```

Compared with symbolic functions, standard functions are *faster* (and don't require the Symbolic Toolbox), and as mentioned above, are not limited to mathematical operations.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I forgot to include that. Thanks. Updated